# Transfer contents of email into outlook

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone help to transfer contents of emails saved in a specific folder on desktop to Microsoft excel using a VBA macro. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
Const fPath As String = "C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\test\" 'The path to save the messages

Sub Download_Outlook_Mail_To_Excel()
    Dim olApp As Object
    Dim olFolder As Object
    Dim olNS As Object
    Dim xlBook As Workbook
    Dim xlSheet As Worksheet
    Dim NextRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim olItem As Object
    Set xlBook = Workbooks.Add
    Set xlSheet = xlBook.Sheets(1)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If Err() <> 0 Then
        Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    With xlSheet
        .Cells(1, 1) = "Sender"
        .Cells(1, 2) = "Subject"
        .Cells(1, 3) = "Date"
        '.Cells(1, 4) = "Size"
        .Cells(1, 5) = "EmailID"
        .Cells(1, 6) = "Body"
        CreateFolders fPath
        Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        Set olFolder = olNS.PickFolder
        For Each olItem In olFolder.Items
            NextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            If olItem.Class = 43 Then
                .Cells(NextRow, 1) = olItem.Sender
                .Cells(NextRow, 2) = olItem.Subject
                .Cells(NextRow, 3) = olItem.SentOn
                '.Cells(NextRow, 4) =
                .Cells(NextRow, 5) = SaveMessage(olItem)
                .Cells(NextRow, 6) = olItem.Body 'Are you sure?
            End If
        Next olItem
    End With
    MsgBox "Outlook Mails Extracted to Excel"
lbl_Exit:
    Set olApp = Nothing
    Set olFolder = Nothing
    Set olItem = Nothing
    Set xlBook = Nothing
    Set xlSheet = Nothing
    Exit Sub
End Sub

Function SaveMessage(olItem As Object) As String
    Dim Fname As String
    Fname = Format(olItem.ReceivedTime, "yyyymmdd") & Chr(32) & Format(olItem.ReceivedTime, "HH.MM") & Chr(32) & olItem.sendername & " - " & olItem.Subject
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(58) & Chr(41), "")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(58) & Chr(40), "")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(34), "-")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(42), "-")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(47), "-")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(58), "-")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(60), "-")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(62), "-")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(63), "-")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(124), "-")
    SaveMessage = SaveUnique(olItem, fPath, Fname)
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Function
End Function

Private Function SaveUnique(oItem As Object, strPath As String, strFileName As String) As String
    Dim lngF As Long
    Dim lngName As Long
    lngF = 1
    lngName = Len(strFileName)
    Do While FileExists(strPath & strFileName & ".msg") = True
        strFileName = Left(strFileName, lngName) & "(" & lngF & ")"
        lngF = lngF + 1
    Loop
    oItem.SaveAs strPath & strFileName & ".msg"
    SaveUnique = strPath & strFileName & ".msg"
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Function
End Function

Private Sub CreateFolders(strPath As String)
    Dim strTempPath As String
    Dim iPath As Long
    Dim vPath As Variant
    vPath = Split(strPath, "\")
    strPath = vPath(0) & "\"
    For iPath = 1 To UBound(vPath)
        strPath = strPath & vPath(iPath) & "\"
        If Not FolderExists(strPath) Then MkDir strPath
    Next iPath
End Sub

Private Function FolderExists(ByVal PathName As String) As Boolean
    Dim nAttr As Long
    On Error GoTo NoFolder
    nAttr = GetAttr(PathName)
    If (nAttr And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then
        FolderExists = True
    End If
NoFolder:
End Function

Private Function FileExists(filespec) As Boolean
    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If fso.FileExists(filespec) Then
        FileExists = True
    Else
        FileExists = False
    End If
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Function
End Function
```

Alt+F11 > Tools > set reference to Excel...

Run this from Excel...

[image]

Finally, if you want to split one cell into many cells, try to run the script below.

```
Sub TryMe()
Call SplitCells
End Sub

    Sub SplitCells()
    'Update 20141024
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
    For Each Rng In WorkRng
        lLFs = VBA.Len(Rng) - VBA.Len(VBA.Replace(Rng, vbLf, ""))
        If lLFs > 0 Then
            Rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(lLFs).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown
            Rng.Resize(lLFs + 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(VBA.Split(Rng, vbLf))
        End If
    Next
    Call SplitCells
    End Sub


Sub SplitCells()
'Update 20141024
Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
For Each Rng In WorkRng
    lLFs = VBA.Len(Rng) - VBA.Len(VBA.Replace(Rng, vbLf, ""))
    If lLFs > 0 Then
        Rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(lLFs).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown
        Rng.Resize(lLFs + 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(VBA.Split(Rng, vbLf))
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you but I'm encountering with the below error

"Compile Error'
"Syntax Error"
Also I don't want the emails to be selected by the macro from outlook
I already have some emails saved in a particular folder on my desktop
I need the only the body of these emails to be pasted without any headers in the excel sheet one after another
Also I dont want the entire body should be thrown into one cell

Comment: Apologies for too many questions, I'm completely new to coding and I have an assignment to be completed asap. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hummm, it works fine for me, so it should work fine for you.  Make sure you set a reference to Excel.  I am updating my OP with a screen shot.  Also, make sure you update this line: Const fPath As String = "C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\test\"
Se it to the actual folder, on your side, that you are downloading emails to. Finally, make sure you have no red text.  I did notice a few weird line breaks when I copied/pasted the code from my OP to my Outlook Module.  You may have to delete a few line-breaks.  Finally, run this script from MS Outlook, not from MS Excel.

Comment: Mark my solution as helpful, if it actually helped you.  It will help, if you get the setup right, as I described above.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I worked well.
But didnt served the purpose, what i need is only the body of the email to be copied in to the excel and it should not throw the entire email body into one cell of the excel.
Can you please help me with this macro?? I'm in much need your help is greatly appreciated.
The previous macro was wonderful!!

Comment: Hi Bro... thanks for your help, the macro worked fine

Comment: I edited it to pull only the body of the email, but the problem is the entire body is throwing in to one single cell.
Can you help to get like first line of body in first cell and second line of body in second cell and son on

Comment: Change the code, just slightly, like this:

            If olItem.Class = 43 Then
                olItem.Body = Replace(olItem.Body, """,""", vbTab)
                .Cells(NextRow, 1) = olItem.Body 'Are you sure?
            End If

Comment: Still the body of the email is throwing into a single cell :(

Comment: Honestly, I tried to run the original script, and I kept getting errors.  I didn't have a lot of free time to debug the original code, so I just edited my original post, for one sub to call another sub.  Check out my updated code.  That should do what you want.  If it doesn't work the first time you try, try and try again.  Tat's how I learned everything I know.  I need to do several things in the next few days I can't help you much more.  Anyway, you should have everything you need, and more, to get this working.